# Payment gateway sender and receiver id not setting up

Tags: ios, paypal

I am integrating paypal payment gateway in my app. Almost integration part is done but i am confused to set the receiver id (Merchant id) and sender id. can anyone please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to set that in order to use Paypal? You can do payment integration with keys(sandbox and production).

Comment: But how would i come to know that receiver received his payment or not ?
The code on which i am working gives success status with id but i am confused that it has been processed or not.